# C++ Dlib load_image_dataset issues

Tags: c++, image-processing, dlib

When loading a set of images using dlibs load_image_dataset as so:

```
//------------
command_line_parser parser; 
parser.parse(argc, argv); //inputs argc, argv as defined by main where argv is an .xml containing all file locations

dlib::array<array2d<rgb_pixel> > images;
std::vector<std::vector<rectangle> > object_locations, ignore;

cout << "Loading image dataset from metadata file " << parser[1] << endl;
ignore = load_image_dataset(images, object_locations, parser[1]);
cout << "Number of images loaded: " << images.size() << endl;
//---------------
```

I get the following error:

```
"dlib::array2d<T, mem_manager> &dlib::array2d<T, mem_manager>::operator=(dlib::array2d<T, mem_manager> &) [with T=dlib::rgb_pixel, mem_manager=dlib::default_memory_manager]" (declared at line 320 of "C:\..path-to-dlib...\dlib-18.16\dlib\..\dlib/image_processing/../image_processing/../matrix/../array2d/array2d_kernel.h") is inaccessible
```

If I try to store an individual image from "images" as so:

```
//--------
array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
img = images[i];
//-----------
```

But no error if i just display it:

```
//------
image_window image_i(images[i], "Image i");
//---------
```

What is happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array2d is non-copyable by design because copying images is expensive and almost always unnecessary.  If you want to move an image around use swap().  If you *really* need to copy an image then you can use the assign_image() function or you can use matrix objects (which are copyable) to represent images instead of array2d.

But really, don't unnecessarily copy images.

Comment: good advice, i'll take it. can you tell me where to find a list of all array2d functions? or more generally, dlib functions. their specs are comprehensive but not easily understood.